# How to detect dtmf tone programmatically in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

How to detect dtmf tone programmatically in iphone?.I want to detect whether the received audio signal (mic input) should be dtmf tone?

Plz help me ? i really strug with this for 2 days.
Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1):

Since the DTMF system uses only 8 pure sine tones, it will be more efficient to use tuned filter banks or the Goertzel algorithm to detect presence of energy at those frequencies than it would be to do FFTs.

The Wikipedia page for the Goertzel algorithm has good psuedo-code for how the algorithm works. It shouldn't be too hard to translate this into (Objective) C.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm

Run your audio through there, and measure the power output every 100 milliseconds or so. It'll be a fair bit of work - good luck!.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 8 narrow band filters and amplitude averaging over small time windows.  These 2 processes are typically done together using variants of the Goertzel algorithm.

The other thing one can do is to measure total average amplitude over all frequencies in the same time window using an RMS averager.  When the energy in just 2 of the filter windows is a majority of the total signal energy, then you probably have a DTMF signal. To decode the DTMF you can do a table lookup based on which 2 filters show the energy.  If there is a lot more total energy everywhere in the audio than than in just 2 of the filters, the whole audio signal probably noise, not a DTMF signal.